# Two icons are present in Ubuntu 17.10. How can I remove one of them?

Tags: 17.10, icons, gnome-shell, activities-overview

I found multiple icons of same software in my installed softwares list. I want to remove one of the icons. How can I remove one icon or merge two icons into one icon?

[image: two icons]

Output of `ls /usr/share/applications/ | grep -i audacious` is

```
audacious.desktop
audacious-qt.desktop
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the outputs of `ls /usr/share/applications/ | grep -i audacious` and `ls ~/.local/share/applications/ | grep -i audacious`.

Comment: output of( ls /usr/share/applications/ | grep -i audacious) are audacious.desktop and audacious-qt.desktop...and  no output for (ls ~/.local/share/applications/ | grep -i audacious)

Answer (score 1):

As per the output of `ls /usr/share/applications/ | grep -i audacious` it seems the icons correspond to `audacious.desktop` and `audacious-qt.desktop`.

Removing one `.desktop` from `/usr/share/applications/` file should work, but it is not a permanent solution (and it is generally not recommended to make changes in the root directory unless you're absolutely sure). Once an associated package gets updated, the `.desktop` file would most certainly reappear.

For a permanent solution copy the `.desktop` file associated to the Audacious launcher you want to get rid of from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/`. Then open the copied file with a text-editor and add (or modify) the following line:

```
NoDisplay=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have both audacious and audacious-qt installed. If you just want to remove one of the icon, I suggest that you look into those files which define the icons using:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/audacious.desktop
```

and

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/audacious-qt.desktop
```

This should tell you which program is executed by clicking the icon so you can decide which one to delete. Remove the .desktop file should remove the icon. Worked for me when I had both  pycharm-ce and pycharm-pro installed.